# IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Tags: android

I got struck because of `IllegalStateException` in the following code. Can anybody please help me? Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logbt);
        final EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loguser);
        final EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.logpw);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user.getText().toString() != "" && pw.getText().toString() != "") {
                    Thread t = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                String postURL = "http://surfkid.redio.de/login";
                                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
                                ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.getText().toString()));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", md5(pw.getText().toString())));
                                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
                                post.setEntity(ent);
                                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
                                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
                                final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                                Log.e("XXX", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("XXX", e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    t.start();
                    // Log.e("XXX",s);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String md5(String in) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.reset();
            digest.update(in.getBytes());
            byte[] a = digest.digest();
            int len = a.length;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
                sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Logcat message:

> 01-18 18:39:53.383: ERROR/XXX(7113):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Content has been consumed

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: Did you saw Logcat next to your console window, if you are not able to saw that, then click Windows Menu, then Click others and Chosse Logcat, and tell us whether you had problem in showing logcat or not,pls be quick

Comment: in the logger no log with XXX appear

Comment: IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Comment: It's because you commented it out :)

Comment: @rofl whats with Log.e("XXX",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

Comment: Ok Cool, So you had Got IllegalStateException, can you copy that Logcat error and paste in your question, or tell me, what is the line number logcat is showing you?

Comment: Click the E option in Your Logcat, Post the Message which are shown in Red Letters, Pls Edit this, because this Clumsy and Ugly too, difficult to read, we want to know where the error is occurred?

Comment: 01-18 18:39:53.383: ERROR/XXX(7113): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Comment: The callstack should also contain the file and line number where your problem occurs.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can consume `Content` only at once from an `Entity`

in the line :

> ```
> final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
> ```

you have consumed content and again you are using the same at here:

> ```
> Log.e("XXX",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
> ```

That why it is causing `IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed`

So the solution is here:

```
String _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); // content will be consume only once
final JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(_response);
Log.e("XXX",_response);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is really useful info.. Consuming of content after httptresponse can be done only once.. i was also doing the same mistake, but now got it perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

it's also happens if you are writing the consuming statement in the Expressions of the **debugger**!!! 
 (e.g if you are doing "watch" to something like `EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)`)

Answer (score 3):

First, this has to be a mistake that every single new android programmer makes and it's asked here every single day. You have

```
user.getText().toString()!= ""&& pw.getText().toString()!= ""
```

This doesn't do what you want it to. You need

```
 !user.getText().toString().equals("")&& !pw.getText().toString().equals("")
```

Also, you need to print the stacktrace. In your exception, you need

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

instead of logging

```
e.toString()
```

Comment: Btw, on this off-topic-topic, I prefer `Log.e(TAG, "Error", exception)` over `exception.toString()`.

Comment: could anyone compile that class (user:test pw:sers)

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with a case of a null check on the entity causing it to be flagged as "consumed". Hope my headache will help someone else out there.

Vikas Patidar's answer helped me figure out the key to the riddle, so many thanks